# Remove the Title Bar of a QT Window While Keeping the Borders in Place

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qml, applicationwindow

I'm having trouble removing the whole title bar of my qt application while keeping the borders in place.

I use the code below but there still remaining part of the title bar as you can see in the picture.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
    color: "white"
}
```

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bzK3.png)

I can use `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` but then I have to implement resizing and shadow.

How can I possibly do this? I just want to replicate the title bar just like on Google Chrome or Firefox. Any idea?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot remove that bar, but if you need a custom `QtQuick` `Window` and do not want to deal with defining custom functionalities, you can try [this repository](https://github.com/wangwenx190/framelesshelper).